# Stack Overflow Error in Java

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm trying to code a program that finds the kth smallest element using recursion and quick sort like partitioning so as not to have to sort the entire array. I feel like my code *should* work, but I get a stack overflow error immediately when the function is called so I can't test it.

I thought stack overflow had to do with overflowing the execution stack, and I understand it happens with recursion, but the error gets called on the very first line of the function so it's confused me. If someone could take a look at this and give some suggestions I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

```
public static int find_kth_smallest( int[] A, int n, int k )
{  
   int[] Left = new int[200];
   int[] Right = new int[200];
   int half = n/2;
   int x = 0; int j = half + 1; int q = 0;
   int count = 0;
   int pivot = A[half];

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       if(A[i] < pivot)
       {
           Left[x] = A[i];
           x++;
       }
       if(A[i] > pivot)
       {
           Right[j] = A[i];
           j++;
       }
   }

   while(Left[q] != 0)
    q++;

   if(k < q)
   {
       return find_kth_smallest(Left, q, k);
   }

   if(k > q)
   {
       return find_kth_smallest(Right, n-q, k);
   }
   if(k-1 == q)
   {
       return A[pivot];
   }

   return -1;
```

Comment: What are the values you pass in as parameters to the functions?

Comment: It's not clear *how* you've debugged this. Just stepping into the method shouldn't cause a problem...

Comment: its gonna die on the first line if its recursive.  Its just that its not the first time its been on the first line, its recursed so many times that its run out of stack

Comment: The error may be happening in first line but it may not be first line of execution . You are using recursion so the first line may be called many times . Please verify your logic by debugging the program.

Comment: @keith +1.  Add some kind of print statement in the function near the top.  You will see that the print output appears many times.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that `j` should start at `0`, not at `half+1`.  Currently, you're copying the portion of your array that is above the pivot into the top half of `Right`.  If you ever follow the right side of the recursion, you're guaranteed that the pivot will forever remain equal to `0` after that point, so you'll never stop recursing.

Also, there are several other problems here:

- You're assuming that no element of `A` is equal to `0`, which is a dangerous assumption.
- You're using fixed `int[200]`'s.  This is Java; you can allocate these things at runtime.  Just let `Right` and `Left` be sized appropriately based on `n`.  Right now your program will fail for every `A` of size 400 or larger.

Answer (score 0):

Surely

```
if(k-1 == q)
   {
```

will never be true, as

```
if(k > q)
   {
```

shields it.